# Can I clone an IQueryable in linq? For UNION purposes?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table of `WorkOrders`. The table has a `PrimaryWorker` & `PrimaryPay` field. It also has a `SecondaryWorker` & `SecondaryPay` field (which can be `null`).

I wish to run 2 very similar queries & union them so that it will return a `Worker` Field & `Pay` field. So if a single `WorkOrder` record had both the `PrimaryWorker` and `SecondaryWorker` field populated I would get 2 records back.

The "where clause" part of these 2 queries is very similar and long to construct. Here's a dummy example

```
var q = ctx.WorkOrder.Where(w => w.WorkDate >= StartDt && w.WorkDate <= EndDt);

if(showApprovedOnly)
{
   q = q.Where(w => w.IsApproved);
}
//...more filters applied
```

Now I also have a search flag called `hideZeroPay`. If that's true I don't want to include the record if the worker was payed $0. But obviously for 1 query I need to compare the `PrimaryPay` field and in the other I need to compare the `SecondaryPay` field.

So I'm wondering how to do this.

Can I clone my base query `q` and make a primary & secondary worker query out of it and then union those 2 queries together?

Comment: What would be nice is being able to clone an IQueryable (which no one has provided any way to do so)... for another DbContext instance. As it stands, if you build up a complex query for one DbContext instance, there's no way to reuse it for another DbContext. You could create a helper to build it, but you still have to rebuild it. It seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead. For example, if you just want to run a CountAsync and Skip/Take/ToListAsync in parallel on the same IQueryable, you cannot, because to safely run them in parallel, you need two separate DbContext instances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmm, I'm not sure that I understand you intention. But I think cloning is not neccessary. Why don't you split two new queries from your base query?

```
var baseQuery = ctx.WorkOrder.Where(w => w.WorkDate >= StartDt && w.WorkDate <= EndDt);

IQueryable<WorkOrder> query1;
if (showApprovedOnly)
{
  query1 = baseQuery.Where(w => w.IsApproved);
}
//more filters on query1
...

IQueryable<WorkOrder> query2;
if (/*something*/)
  query2 = baseQuery.Where(w => w.SomeThing);
```

After defining your queries you can interpret them (per enumeration) and retrieve your different results.

```
var res1 = query1.ToList();
var res2 = query2.ToList();
```

Comment: Oh! For some reason I was thinking I was always adding to the same query object, but you're saying it is infact a new distinct query object returned eachtime you call a linq function like where().. like how String.Substring() returs a new String & not the same one modified?

If that's the case that's great. How is the best way to return the union of query1 & query2? Ideally I'd like it to all run on the database.

Comment: After thinking about it, I've to say that your thoughts came up too. The reason is the ObjectQuery object. Well when I was writing my answer I just was guessing but now I know that it works.
I don't know if a .Union() is executed on the database. But I'm interested on your results, after you have tried it. ;o)

Comment: Yeah, it does seem you get a new ObjectQuery back each time because query1.equals(query2) returns false.

I noticed that I had to perform my projection ( Select() ) on each query before calling Union() for it to work properly.

I then ran a ToTraceString() on the ObjectQuery and it does all apear to run on the DB.

Answer (score 1):

When you do your second Where you are actually cloning your query.

Here you create your initial queryable object.

```
var q = ctx.WorkOrder.Where(w => w.WorkDate >= StartDt && w.WorkDate <= EndDt);
```

Here you create a new queryable with the where associated

```
if(showApprovedOnly)
{
   q = q.Where(w => w.IsApproved);
}
//...more filters applied
```

All you need to do is create a new variable to store the ammended query.

```
var qw = q.Where(w=> w.IsApproved);
```

This works because the queryable is created as an object and the query itself is only run once you enumerate it.